# FutureTask и неблокирующая проверка завершения

Tags: java, concurrency

Как известно, метод get у фьючера приводит к блокировке текущего потока. Требуется получить результат без блокировки. Вариант с методами isDone/isCancelled и с последующим вызовом get приводит к эксепшену:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)

Сам код большой, поэтому приведу только вариант, где эксепшен воспроизводится (2-й while для воспроизведения ошибки):

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsNum);
        List<Future<ResultWrapper>> futures = new LinkedList<Future<ResultWrapper>>();
        class DownloadCallable implements Callable<ResultWrapper> {
           @Override
           public ResultWrapper call() {
               ...
            }
         ...
        dc = new DownloadCallable();
        futures.add(executor.submit(dc));
            ...             
        final Iterator<Future<ResultWrapper>> it = futures.iterator();
        try {
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                final Future<ResultWrapper> fut = it.next();
                while (!(fut.isDone() || fut.isCancelled())) {
                    Thread.sleep(DATA_TIMEOUT);
                }
Exception-->    ResultWrapper res = fut.get();
                if (res != null) {
                    results.add(res);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Если 2-й while убрать, то код отрабатывает нормально.
Почему так происходит? И как лучше реализовать неблокирующую проверку окончания работы callable потоков?

Comment: Возникает очень важный вопрос: зачем? Приведенная вами реализация все равно блокриует текущий поток (т.е. он не может выполнять никакую другую работу, пока executor не прекратит обрабатывать задачи).

Comment: Это только пример для воспроизведения эксепшена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено. Эксепшен был связан с выходом за границы массива в callable потоке.